# Importing variable into Perl package

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm writing a basic program whose core logic is split across several project-specific modules for cleanliness (keeping subroutines organised by their purpose in the program's logic).

Suddenly had trouble exposing an option from the `main` package in one of the modules, and using the `our` statement appeared to have no effect.

For brevity, I'll copy+paste an isolated test case I wrote to examine this behaviour:

### main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename;

# The variable to be read by the module.
our $verbose = 1;

# Load Output.pm from directory
use lib dirname "$0";
use Output;

write_message "Hello, world\n";
```

### Output.pm

```
package Output;
use warnings;
use strict;
use parent "Exporter";
our @EXPORT = qw(write_message);

# Should be imported?
our $verbose;

sub write_message {
    print $_[0] unless !$verbose;
}

1;
```

**Expected result:** `"Hello, world"`
**Actual result:** Dead silence

It's quite possible that what I'm trying to achieve isn't even possible in Perl, as this isn't the intended use of modules (and heck, I understand why that'd be the case).

I'm still quite new to Perl and there are some things I'm struggling to wrap my head around. I've seen people recommend using the `our` declarator to expose a variable across packages, but I can't understand why this isn't working.

**PS:** If anybody knows a better approach to splitting an app's program-specific logic between modules, I'd appreciate some pointers too. :) But first and foremost, I'd prefer to learn why `our`-ing a variable isn't working.

Comment: Sorry realized that I understood wrong.

Comment: All good, was wondering why my comment couldn't be posted, haha.

Comment: All good means "Happens, it's alright" or "undelete it please"? :))

Comment: "All good" means "no hard feelings, my friend, I understand people make mistakes". =)

Comment: The expression `print $_[0] unless !$verbose` is the kind of thing that sends maintenance programmers looking for you while wielding an axe. Why not `print $_[0] if $verbose`?

Comment: @DaveCross: Because this was an adhoc example case I wrote to help explain what I was trying to understand, and it's easier to say "Dead silence" instead of "This guy shouldn't be saying anything". Semantics really don't matter much in hypothetical examples. I would've written "foo"/"bar" instead but I'm just so damn sick of seeing that.

Comment: @Alhadis you misunderstood what Dave was referring to.  He was referring to the syntax you used in the print statement.

Comment: Ah, right. Yeah, sorry, I think I only used an `unless` statement because I'd just finished writing one elsewhere when it came to scribbling down something hypothetical, haha. My bad, my head's elsewhere. Split between six different packages, to be precise.

Comment: @Alhadis: I can't say your idea of splitting your code across modules sounds ideal, but it's hard to tell exactly what you mean or to suggest a better alternative unless we can see the code. You may be better of with an object-oriented solution

Comment: @DaveCross HAHAHAH, HOLY MOTHBALLS, I thought you meant `if ($verbose){ print $_[0]; }`, I had no idea Perl actually let you stick an `if` statement AFTER a command. `print $_[0] if $verbose` actually works, holy hell. I can see what you meant, now... I'm loving this language. #stillanewbie

Comment: @Borodin Yeah I know, but I think I had the wrong interpretation of how variables are handled inside/across packages... I guess I mistook it as being analogous to `global $verbose;` in PHP, probably due to writing the latter language too much. Anyway, this is pretty weird code that I'll probably hate in six months time when I'm writing Perl more fluently, so I'd prefer not to be judged too harshly on it, haha.

Comment: So you knew you could use "unless" there, but didn't realise you could use "if" instead. Interesting :-)

Comment: @DaveCross Am I on trial for being a newcomer to Perl, now?

Comment: No, no. Not at all. I have a professional interest in the way that people learn Perl and was really interested that someone's understanding could get into that state. No criticism intended at all.

Comment: Ehh... my native language is JavaScript, and I'm used to conditionals preceding declarations. I've been learning Perl in a rather non-linear fashion, and learned about the "unless" operator while seeing it following an assignment. I assumed this was a feature native to Perl's syntax, and not something that carried over to "if" as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `our` statement just creates a package variable (whereas `my` creates a lexical variable). It has nothing to do with exporting

The best option is probably to declare the variable in the `Output` package and access it as `$Output::verbose` elsewhere. Like this

#### main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use lib dirname $0;
use Output;

$Output::verbose = 1;

write_message "Hello, world\n";
```

#### Output.pm

```
package Output;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 5.57 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw/ write_message /;

our $verbose;

sub write_message {
    print $_[0] if $verbose;
}

1;
```

Note that I have also removed the incorrect quotes from around `$0`, and ever since version 5.57 of `Exporter` it has been possible (and preferable) to *import* it's `import` subroutine instead of subclassing it

Comment: Think I'm beginning to grok with Perl, now. What I'm trying to do is probably better accomplished using a specialist package for abstracting options (e.g., $Options::verbose) and having those declarations used across the remainder of an app's private modules. Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`our` declares a package variable *in the current package*. The one in main.pl refers to `$main::verbose`; the one in Output.pm refers to `$Output::verbose`.

You can use the full name `$main::verbose` to access the variable from anywhere, but you can't really "export" it because exporting refers to making symbols accessible to users of your module. You're trying to do the opposite.

Comment: Yep, just realised when I read Borodin's answer. Thanks! (See the first comment I left there).